# Resolving Expo Error: [Error] XDLError: ValidationError: "devClient" is not allowed

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Getting this when trying to load the iOS simulator from expo.

Error: [Error] XDLError: ValidationError: "devClient" is not allowed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Delete the `.expo` directory and re-run `expo start` to resolve this.

Comment: From the project root directory

Comment: Works for XDLError: no scheme specified for development client as well